# Best place to add configuration - controller, model or helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

NOTE: I am not saving any data into the db. Just rendering it into an email

I am trying to move this function from my model:

```
  def self.email_enabled?(object)
    (object.portal_type == Portal::SITE || object.portal_type == Portal::APP) && Rails.application.config.send_portal_setup_email
  end
```

into a helper, and this is what I have tried:

```
  def email_enabled?(object)
    (object.portal_type == Portal::SITE || object.portal_type == Portal::APP) && Rails.application.config.send_portal_setup_email
  end
```

but the view doesn't recognize it. Would a better place for it be the controller?

Does anyone know of any guides that explain this?

Answer (score 1):

Remember that in order to see results in your view you have to include the helper class into your controller that renders the view.

```
class MyController < ApplicationController

include MyHelper

# rest of your controller code
end
```